# Could not find imported module support code for aws_s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I am trying to apply default encrytion as "aws:kms" to s3 bucket which was created earlier however, I am getting below error;

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Could not find imported module support code for aws_s3.  Looked for either HAS_MD5.py or s3.py"
}
```

I am using below code:-

```
  - name: Create S3 bucket
    aws_s3:
      bucket: "{{aws_environment}}-mybucket"
      mode: create
      encrypt: yes
      encryption_kms_key_id: "arn:aws:kms:{{aws_environment}}:{{project_name}}:key/{{kmskey}}"
      encryption_mode: aws:kms
      region: "{{aws_region}}"
```

python version is `python 2.7.14`
ansible version is `2.6.2` which is defined in `requirements.txt` [pip install -q -r requirements.txt]

requirements.txt:-

```
ansible==2.6.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
bcrypt==3.1.4
cffi==1.11.5
cryptography==2.3.1
enum34==1.1.6
idna==2.7
ipaddress==1.0.22
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
paramiko==2.4.1
psutil==5.4.1
pyasn1==0.4.4
pycparser==2.18
PyNaCl==1.2.1
PyYAML==3.13
six==1.11.0
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.7.79
awscli==1.15.80
dig==0.1.10
dnspython==1.15.0
```

As per ansible documentation, parameters like `encryption_kms_key_id` and `encryption_mode` are not supported in ansible version 2.6.2 hence, I have downloaded `aws_s3.py` and `s3.py` libraries from ansible latest version 2.10 and referring them in my project repository under `ansible/library` but still getting the above error.

Do I need to use python3 interpreter for this? Kindly advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Ansible 2.10 changed quite radically how modules are named, with a new concept of builtin and community collections. Your first try should be to use the Python files from 2.9 rather.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried "aws_s3.py" file from 2.7/2.8 versions and found error was no more exist however, default s3 encryption setting "aws:kms" is not getting applied.
I have raised it with ansible github issue.

Comment: Ansible has advised me to upgrade it to latest version which I had tried but unfortunately settings were not getting applied to s3 bucket. Finally, I have used aws s3api cli to put encryption which solved the problem.